# the timing of using the Scanner.nextLine() method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

From P.40 of the textbook 'Data Structures and Algorithms in Java, 6/e' 
(the code is slightly revised):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Invalid int; pls enter an int: ");
}
int i = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.print(i);
```

If I type a non-integer value(that's to say: 1.0) by System.in, it would enter the while loop body since the boolean of `!scanner.hasNextInt()` is true.

However I don't understand the syntax the author puts in another line of `scanner.nextLine();` inside the while loop in Line 4, does it generate anything? Why can't the program work if I delete the `scanner.nextLine();` line? (and somehow pc memory almost get full after deleting it..)

Comment: This is to get rid of the non integer input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @Guy said is correct. The `hasNext` function call does not do anything to advance your input pointer. `hasNextInt` checks if your next input is an integer, but to advance to the next line after this input, you need to call a `next` function. Otherwise, you will forever be checking `hasNextInt` on your non-integer input, going into an infinite loop, which is why your memory usage is super high.

Comment: I see....  does that mean if I deleted the `next` function, it won't even enter the while loop body for me to type another input?

Comment: @JasonChi-HanHuang Think of it this way. Assuming you have an input stream, you start reading at index 0. The `hasNext` function checks the subsequent index until a terminator (null or new line). When you call `next`, your read index is now advanced to after that terminator. If you delete the next function, you will be constantly checking for input after index 0, which is the same thing. You are already inside the while loop, but you are not reading the next input unless the `next` function is called.

Comment: Thanks for making more explanation @absolutelydevastated